# How to automatic send data without a form or submit

Tags: php

I'd like to send data from a php file to another php file. 
I don't wana use a form!
In case it is possible i don't even wana use javascript.
So i was thinking:

```
//File 1.php
SEND $data TO href='2.php';
echo 'window.location = "2.php"'; // i know this is Js 

//File 2.php
$_GET['data'];
echo $data;
```

No submit button!

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you `include '2.php';` all variables from `1.php` will be available in `2.php`.

Comment: @jeroen interesting. Yes, id like to have some variables form that first file to the next. But if i do include it... doesn't the whole script runs again?

Comment: What do you mean, *again*?

Comment: First you have a form were you enter data and pressing submit. Then a php file is checking what you have posted and goes threw diffrent cases. If the form is submited fine you will be redirected to a new page. On this new page i need some data from last page. But if i do include the last page all scripts will run again, but with no POST send to it, and therefore no variables will be filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send it via the URL, that's what GET method is for (amongst other things) :)

```
header("Location: 2.php?data=HelloGirls");
```

Then 2.php can fetch is using `$_GET`

```
echo $_GET['data'];
```

+No JS required anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be the code of the **first** php file which will submit the data to the 2nd php file

```
$content = http_build_query (array (
'field1' => 'Value1',
'field2' => 'Value2',
'field3' => 'Value3',
.....................
.....................
.....................
));

$context = stream_context_create (array (
'http' => array (
'method' => 'POST',
'content' => $content,
)
));

$result = file_get_contents('your2ndphpfile.php', null, $context);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use file_get_contents(); to get data from another file.

But i think there is now any way that you can send data from one php file to another php file without form submission